# click-event in php to retrieve downloadable file.

Tags: javascript, php, http-proxy, php-curl

I have to download a csv file from a site. previously there was a form action url which can be programmed to download the file but now it is a selection button without any action url (only '#').And completely manipulated by JS. When i click 'Domains as csv' then csv file will download but i want to do it when the script runs only.whenever i run the php script I can access and download the pages with the help of action url but that specific file is not retrievable. please any idea how to deal such issue? 
[image]

php script :

```
$proxy_host = "internet.com.ag";
$proxy_port = "1111";
$proxy = "$proxy_host:$proxy_port";
$teliko_credentials = array("username"=>"com", "pass"=>'com');
$url = '//domain.net/';
$url = '//domain.net/#';
//$url = /domain.net/#DomainOverview/Domains';
$fileExt = ".csv";
$file = '';
function curl_session($url, $proxy, $credentials ) {
    $ch = curl_init(); //init curl
    // snippet for via proxy authentication
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //login form action url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); // passing proxy details 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); //If url has redirects then go to the final redirected URL.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // ENABLE HTTP POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user='. $credentials['username'] .'&password='.urlencode( $credentials['pass'] ).'&submit=Login'); //Set the post parameters
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); //Handle cookies for the login
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //not to print out the results of its query. Instead, it will return the results as a string return value
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $file = curl_exec($ch); // retrieves the source file
    return $file;
    curl_close($ch);
}
$file = curl_session($url ,$proxy, $credentials);
if ($file != '')
    file_put_contents('\\W516014\Exchange\http\fs\Export-'.date("d.m.Y").$fileExt, $file);// download file into the specified directory 
?>
```

Comment: Press F12, look in the network tab - see the request and if you are lucky it is a readable link. The code you have posted now is not relevant to the dropdown you show

Comment: @mplungjan yes you are right. actually, can't figure it out how to proceed in such scenario. Its only showing js script as an initiator in network tab no link at all.

Comment: There should be an ajax call or similar

Comment: xmlHttpRequest object, may be I have to manipulate this object in php

Comment: Use curl.... ....